# Vertical and horizontal scroll in Html table

Tags: html, css

I have a table as shown in image.
I need to add Vertical and horizontal scrolls. While scrolling vertically The top row should be fixed and all other rows should scroll. But while scrolling horizontally, the left column should be fixed and top row will move horizontally.
In other words, The top row will move horizontally only and left column vertically only.
How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. We can use js plugin.
sortable_table.js, fixed_table_rc.js

```
$('#fixed_hdr2').fxdHdrCol({
    fixedCols:  1,
    width:     "100%",
    height:    500,
    colModal: [
           { width: 50, align: 'left' },
           { width: 110, align: 'left' },
           { width: 170, align: 'left' },
           { width: 250, align: 'left' },
           { width: 100, align: 'left' },
           { width: 70, align: 'left' },
           { width: 100, align: 'left' },
           { width: 100, align: 'left' },
           { width: 90, align: 'left' },
           { width: 400, align: 'left' }
    ],
    sort: true
});
```